# Output text in text box not multi-line, word wrap set to true in text box property

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the text box to my winform to be multi-line but I can't figure out how to do it. It just comes out as one line.  Word wrap is set to true.  Do I also have to set it to true within my code?  Have I screwed up my formatting somehow?  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is the code:

```
public override string  ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} Pizzas @ {1:C}: {2:C}\n" +
            "{3} Cokes @ {4:C}  {5:C}\n" +
            "Order Amount: {6:C}\n" +
            "Sales Tax: {7:C}\n" +
            "Amount Due: {8:C}\n" +
            "Amount Paid: {9:C}\n" +
            "Change Due: {10:C}", numberOfPizzas, PIZZA_PRICE, 
            totalCostOfPizza, numberOfCokes, COKE_PRICE, totalCostOfCoke,
            foodAndDrinkTotal, totalSalesTax, totalAmountDue, amountPaid, 
            changeDue);
    }        

........

private void btnPaymentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        amountPaid = double.Parse(this.txtAmountPaid.Text);

        orderPaymentObject = new Payment(orderObject.TotalAmountDue, amountPaid);

        this.txtNumberOfPizzaOrdered.Clear();
        this.txtNumberOfCokesOrdered.Clear();
        this.txtAmountDue.Clear();
        this.txtAmountPaid.Clear();

        this.lblYourOrder.Visible = true;
        this.txtYourOrder.Visible = true;

        this.txtYourOrder.Text =  orderObject.ToString();               
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In windows you need both a carriage return \r and a line feed \n to get a newline.  So in your example above you would need to change every \n into a \r\n.

Also, you may not have set the [Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a RichTextBox instead of a Textbox